# Ghostscript and JPEG2000 images

Tags: pdf, images, redhat-enterprise-linux, ghostscript

Using gs 8.71, RedHat

I'm having trouble converting pdf files that have jpeg2000 images embedded within.  Part of the coding is to reduce the pdf image by 10% using the -c <> setpagedevice command.  This command will work properly if the pdf file does NOT have a jpeg2000 image; however, if the pdf file does have a JPEG2000 image, the ghostscript command will hang and produce a "ERROR: Unable to process JPXDecode data. Page will be missing data".

Is there any parameter I can pass to gs to allow it to not hang if it encounters a jpeg2000 image?  We can deal with the pdf file being incorrect for a jpeg2000 image, but cannot deal with the program simply hanging when executing.

I have also tried compiling gs 9.15 and running under RedHat (with better, but not great, results) but prefer to use the latest greatest from RedHat.